# Object required error en Excel

Tags: vba, excel, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a pull list from excel data and finally wrote this code:

```
Sub subPartsQueue()
Dim part As String
Dim numParts As Integer
Dim subPart As String
Dim numSubparts As Integer
Dim mach As String
Dim state As Integer
Dim startH As Date
Dim endH As Date
Dim difH As Integer
Dim difM As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim z As Integer

z = 2

numParts = ThisWorbook.Sheets("partsQueue").Range("G1")
numSubparts = ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("S2")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("A1") = "Subpart"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("B1") = "Start time"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("C1") = "End time"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("D1") = "Nº of Reps"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("E1") = "Acumulated loot"

For x = 2 To numParts
    part = ThisWorbook.Sheets("partsQueue").Range("A" & x)
    startH = ThisWorbook.Sheets("partsQueue").Range("B" & x)
    For y = 2 To numSubparts
        If ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("A" & y) = part Then
            mach = ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("D" & y)
            If part = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("machines").Range(mach & "3") Then
                endH = DateAdd("n", ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("I" & y), startH)
            Else
                endH = DateAdd("n", ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("J" & y), startH)
            End If
           If freeMachine(mach, startH) = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("machines").Range(mach & "1") = 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("machines").Range(mach & "2") = endH
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("machines").Range(mach & "3") = ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("B" & y)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("A" & z) = ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("B" & y)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("B" & z) = startH
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("C" & z) = endH
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("D" & z) = numReps(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("A" & z), z) + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("E" & z) = acumulatedLoot(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("A" & z), z, ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("H" & y), ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("K" & y), ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("L" & y))
            If sameMold(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("A" & z), ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("C" & y)) = True Then
                z = z + 1
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("A" & z) = otherSubpartMold(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("A" & z - 1), ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("C" & y))
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("B" & z) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("B" & z - 1)
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("C" & z) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("C" & z - 1)
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("D" & z) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("D" & z - 1)
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("E" & z) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("E" & z - 1)
                z = z + 1
            Else
                z = z + 1
            End If
           Else
            Resume Next
           End If
        End If
    Next y
Next x

End Sub

Function freeMachine(machine As String, startH As Date) As Boolean

Dim difH As Integer
Dim difM As Integer

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("machines").Range(machine & "1") = 0 Then
    freeMachine = True
Else
    difH = DateDiff("h", startH, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("machines").Range(machine & "2"))
    difM = DateDiff("n", startH, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("machines").Range(machine & "2"))
    If difH = 0 Then
        If difM = 0 Then
            freeMachine = True
        Else
            freeMachine = False
        End If
    Else
        freeMachine = False
    End If
End If

End Function

Function numReps(subPart As String, numEntries As Integer) As Integer
x As Integer
y As Integer

y = 0

For x = numEntries To 2 Step -1
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("A" & x) = subPart Then
        y = y + 1
    Else
        y = 0
    End If
Next x

numReps = y

End Function

Function acumulatedLoot(subPart As String, numEntries As Integer, loot As Integer, units As Integer, uses As Integer) As Integer
x As Integer
total As Integer

total = 0

For x = numEntries To 2 Step -1
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("A" & x) = subPart Then
        total = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("E" & x) + (loot * units * uses)
        GoTo out
    Else
        total = loot * units * uses
    End If
Next x

out:
acumulatedLoot = total

End Function

Function sameMold(subPart As String, mold As String) As Boolean
x As Integer
numSubparts As Integer
numSubparts = ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("S2")

For x = 2 To numSubparts
    If mold = ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("C" & x) Then
        If subPart = ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("B" & x) Then
            Resume Next
        Else
            GoTo out
        End If
    Else
        Resume Next
    End If
Next x

out:
sameMold = True

End Function

Function otherSubpartMold(subPart As String, mold As String) As String
x As Integer
numSubparts As Integer
otherSubpartName As String
numSubparts = ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("S2")

For x = 2 To numSubparts
    If mold = ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("C" & x) Then
        If subPart = ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("B" & x) Then
            Resume Next
        Else
            otherSubpartName = ThisWorbook.Sheets("relations").Range("B" & x)
            GoTo out
        End If
    Else
        Resume Next
    End If
Next x

out:
otherSubpartMold = otherSubpartName

End Function
```

But when I run it send me a "Object Required" error in this line:

```
numParts = ThisWorbook.Sheets("partsQueue").Range("G1")
```

Where is a CountA formula of the data contained in A Column of partsQueue.

I tried to use Set before the sentence and activate the sheet but the same error showed up. Reading the code I didn't find an error or something is missing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo : `ThisWorbook` should be `ThisWorKbook` ;)

**Advise : Use `Option Explicit` at the start of each module** 

You can have it automatically in VBE Options (Tools->Options) : *Mandatory Variables Declaration*

Comment: This has been an embarrassing mistake. Thanks for the help, I'll try it now.

Comment: @Tilan04 : No worries, typos are frequent! But with `Option Explicit` you should avoid them far more easily! ;) They'll be pointed out at compilation and not at runtime! ;)